# Añadir documento a una colleccion en cloud firestore

Tags: ionic, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-framework

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en ionic que requiere registro para consultar y escribir en cloud firestore.

Por el momento creo el usuario y puedo realizar consultar, pero lo que me gustaría hacer es que, cuando se registra un usuario nuevo, se cree un nuevo documento con su uid, de forma que, de la ruta inicial cuelguen todos los usuarios (cada uid representa un usuario registrado).

Adjunto foto donde debería crearse el usuario con su uid.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias.

Saludos.

Comment: creo que faltó que colocaras el código que usas para realizar el registro, así poder analizarlo y darte ideas

Comment: No publiqué código porque lo que tengo no me funciona, no obstante, lo que tengo es esto:

var uid = session.uid;        
this.asf.collection('extraHours').add({uid})

Haciendo esto, lo que me crea es un campo uid con el valor del uid del usuario, pero eso no es lo que quiero